# Android layout glitch: reusing 9-patch image as backgrounds

Tags: java, android, nine-patch

I'm making a minesweeper app in AndroidStudio, and have a layout which I dynamically add the buttons to. I have tried multiple layouts and button types, which have all given me the same problem. I have created 9-patch images for the different background states:
[image: down]
[image: up]
[image: red]
which I set for each button using `btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_up)`.

This all works fine normally, however if the buttons are made **too small** or there are **too many** of them, the screen displays strange glitch shapes. The glitch is made worse the larger the number of buttons, and the smaller the size of the buttons. The images below show respectively: small buttons/big grid; slightly bigger buttons; using the red 9-patch as the default background.

[image: bad]
[image: slight]
[image: red]

This is fixed by using normal `png` images but I would quite like to use the scalable 9-patch ones. Clicking the buttons changes the glitch shapes, tending to improve the visibility. I have tried simplifying the layout, and I am sure nothing else is affecting it - it is as simple as I've stated. The glitch shapes seem to originate in the top-left corner, and contain the colour of the 9-patch image, as you can see in the screenshots.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?